# Attach static shadow to bottom of dynamic physicsBody ball in Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to create this as the picture shows

[image]

I got a normal physicsBody ball, with dynamic, affectedByGravity and can rotate.
The thing is, whenever you attach a child to the ball that can rotate, the sprite will follow the same movement as the ball.

What's the best way to make the shadow stay on bottom of the ball? Can I directly do:

```
ball.addChild(shadow)
```

With some kind of attributes that will keep it static on bottom? Or should i

```
self.addChild(shadow)
```

And then during update()

```
shadow.position(ball's position)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add the shadow as child of the ball, you won't have to worry about the position, but you will have to correct for the ball's rotation. I haven't used SpriteKit in a while, but it should be possible to query the ball's rotation and apply one with the opposite angle to the shadow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a `SKShader` to apply simple shadow effect.

You'll need to create an empty file with a `.fsh` extension, let's use `shader.fsh`. The shader code will generate a `z` property which is the "pseudo" depth based on the distance of each pixel to the center of the image. Using `z`, it calculates a normal, and the shadow strength is the dot product of the normal and the light position (here I've placed the light in the top left of the scene):

```
void main()
{
    vec2 coord = (v_tex_coord - 0.5) * 2.0;

    if (length(coord) > 1.0) {
        discard;
    }

    vec3 diffuseColor = SKDefaultShading().rgb;

    vec3 lightPosition = normalize(vec3(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

    float z = sqrt(1.0 - coord.x * coord.x - coord.y * coord.y);
    vec3 normal = normalize(vec3(coord.x, coord.y, z));

    float shadow = max(0.0, dot(normal, lightPosition));

    diffuseColor *= shadow;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuseColor, 1.0);
}
```

You can now shade a shape node like this:

```
    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 50)
    ball.fillColor = .yellow()
    ball.strokeColor = .clear()

    ball.fillShader = SKShader(fileNamed: "shader.fsh")
```

..and, for your sprite node, simply set the `shader` property:

```
    ball.shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "shader.fsh")
```

Then using this image:

[image]

The shaded version looks like:

[image]

Cheers!

Simon

Comment: omg, didn't know there was an SKShader..i'm new in Swift thanks a lot Simon! Can i use the same shader for the ball floor shadow??? you know, the ellipsis style of shadow? would that be "smart" enough to resize and change its alpha due to ball's height??? Because right now im handling all that by doing it manually on the update function...

Comment: You can't really use this technique to cast a shadow - it's really only going to work for shading a sprite to give that 3D effect. Similarly, it's not aware of the ball's position in space - so that shadow is entirely controlled by  `lightPosition` and the first argument of the `max`.

Comment: Oh, i see that the shader moves also with the balls rotation, it follows it, and also, i see that is a shader with black background, am i doing anything wrong? created an empty file called shader.fsh and put it as a ball.shader

Comment: You need your existing sprite node (with the ball image) and set the shader property on it. Also, I don't think SKShaders work in the simulator.

Comment: Yes, i got my ball with its SKSpriteNode, and i'm using my real iphone 6S to test my game

Comment: Does your ball image have an alpha channel? the background needs an alpha of zero (as my shader is written). Can you post the code as a separate question (or edit to this one)?

Comment: The ball right now has alpha = 1. Is that what you ask?

Comment: I meant the space around the outside of the ball should be transparent - it's an artwork change.

Comment: Hi, I've changed my shader code to remove the black background - now you can use any artwork with a centered ball.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116156/discussion-between-simon-gladman-and-msqar).

Comment: Yea, but remember im using a Sprite, and it has transparent background on it. Just the ball. Does this work only with SKShapeNode?

Comment: I've changed that code now - it works with both and you no longer need a transparent background :)

Comment: Btw, there's no way to make the shader rotate the same way as the ball right? otherwise the shader rotates too and that looks weird :D Thanks.

Comment: @SimonGladman This is awesome. Quick question: how would I go about disallowing the shader's rotation? I need the shadow to always be on the bottom of the ball, regardless of the ball's rotation. Thanks!